# String comparison in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, whitespace

I am working on JQuery mentioned below

```
jQuery("select[name='hideLineItemColumns_quote'] option:selected").each(function () {

    var columnName = $.trim($(this).text());


    $('thead.line-item-grid-header tr th').filter(function () {

        return $.trim($('div', this).text()) == columnName;
    }).hide();

});
```

So based on the selected option of the Select tag, Jquery will hide respective columns in a table. Everything is working fine except one scenario, when columnName = "List Price" it doesn't work. If I specifically mention "List Price" in

```
return $.trim($('div', this).text()) == "List Price";
```

it works fine. Is there anything I am missing?

Below is the html for select dropdown

```
<select name="hideLineItemColumns_quote" multiple="true" style="width:100%;" size="4" class="form-input ">
<option value="__part_desc">Description</option>
<option value="__part_number">Product</option>
<option value="_costEa_line">Cost</option>
<option value="_listPriceEach_line">List&nbsp;Price</option>
</select>
```

and below is code for thead

```
<thead class="line-item-grid-header">
    <tr>
        <th align="center" class="list-label ">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:60px;">List Price</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

it looks like instead of space it showing `&nbsp;` in firebug, any workaround ?

Thanks,
Nitesh

Comment: you should post snippet of html also, not enough info.

Answer (score 2):

The [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (U+00A0 Unicode, 160 decimal, `&nbsp;`) is not the same as the [space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29) (U+0020 Unicode, 32 decimal). Well, both of them seems to be a "space", but they are absolutely different characters.

One possible workaround is that for the time of checking you convert non-breaking spaces into simple spaces:

```
$.trim($('div', this).text()) == columnName.replace(/\u00A0/g, ' ')
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EYUsr/)

Answer (score 1):

You have `List&nbsp;Price` in your HTML which is not equal to "List Price" in code.

Comment: I also tried doing this `var columnName = $.trim($(this).text().replace('&nbsp;',' '));` , still no luck

Comment: This jsfiddle is what I want to do http://jsfiddle.net/efh4a/9/ but List Price is still showing up. But If I explicitly define List Price it works http://jsfiddle.net/efh4a/8/

Comment: This works now: http://jsfiddle.net/efh4a/14/. Note I changed to `.html()` for `columnName`

Answer (score 1):

better you use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
 $("div:contains('List Price')")
```

also see [jQuery.contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)